# Macports caffe wrong python

Tags: python, anaconda, macports, caffe

I installed caffe using Macports `sudo port install caffe`. However, Macports didn't use my anaconda python, which I would like to use for development. I can only `import caffe` in Macports' `python2.7`.

Is there a way to show anaconda python where to look or do I have to reinstall for anaconda python? Either way, I would be grateful for a hint how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacPorts never installs modules for use with other Python versions than MacPorts' own version. As a consequence, there is no switch to select the Python version to build against.

You'll have to install `caffe` for your Anaconda Python yourself, e.g. in a virtualenv, or use MacPorts Python.

Comment: I ended up using MacPort's Python, but the virtualenv solution sure sounds elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Install pyvenv ... it is easy to do on a Mac - then you can use whatever you want to.